# Gradle: Who should declare multiproject dependencies: root or subproject

Tags: gradle, multi-project

I like to setup a usual multi project build with gradle. The project structure looks like the following:

```
root/
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
  share/
    build.gradle
  domain/
    build.gradle
  web/
    build.gradle
```

As you might guess, domain depends on share and web depends on share and domain.

There are two ways to descripe this dependenies:

1. specify the dependencies for all sub projects in `root/build.gradle`
2. specify the dependencies per sub project in `root/{sub_project}/build.gradle`

I prefer the second option because a project should know its dependencies. Is there anything wrong about this approach? I ask because the most examples found in the internet and in the gradle documentation uses approach 1.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by 1. It could mean to declare common dependencies in `allprojects` (which is fine), or it could mean to only use a single build script for configuring multiple projects (I prefer to have a separate build script for each project).

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct approaches, the project we're building using gradle uses the second approach, keeps the knowledge of the domain localized and easy to change.